# NextJS is spamming requests to Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have just started using Firebase so I'm trying it with NextJS. I tried to make a Blog system, posting and querying works, but I have just noticed that Firestore shows that I have used 153K reads, so I tried putting a log to the request, and.. yes It's spamming it.

Here's the code for the Posts component.

```js
function Posts() {
    const [blog, setBlog]: any = useState([]);

    getDocs(dbInstance)
        .then((data) => {
            setBlog(data.docs.map((item) => {
                console.log(item.id)
                return { ...item.data(), id: item.id }
            }));
        }).catch(() => {

    })
    return (
        blog.map((post: any) => {
            return (
                <div className={"border"} key={post.id}>
                    <span>ID: {post.id}</span>
                    <h3>Title: {post.title}</h3>
                    <p>Body: {post.body}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably put your getDocs on a `useEffect`.

The problem relies on the loop renders you make.

First render is when creating the component, it set the blog to empty Array, then the fetch call will set the new value causing a new re rendering, but the new rendering will call the getDocs again and so on.

To avoid this put write something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getDocs(dbInstance)
        .then((data) => {
            setBlog(data.docs.map((item) => {
                console.log(item.id)
                return { ...item.data(), id: item.id }
            }));
    }).catch(() => {})
}, []);
```

Note the empty square brackets it means no dependency, so the useEffect will be triggered only the first render of this component.